# Верстка сложного фона

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, html5, canvas

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сверстать фон для входа на сайт.
Моя реализация в следующем: круги обычные div с position:absolute, но они ширины и высоты блоков заданы в vw и vh соответственно. 
Вопрос в следующем: как привязать к среднему кругу иконки?
Пробовал через абсалютное позиционирование но это очень и очень криво...

Comment: А почему бы просто не нарисовать этот фон?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы на вашем месте использовал `transform`

```js
// для автоматизации с помощью jq расположим круги
const randomInteger = (min, max) => {
  let rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1)
  rand = Math.round(rand);
  return rand;
}
const center = document.querySelector('.center');
const divs = center.querySelectorAll('div');
const r = 100; // радиус окружности, на которой будут находится элементы
[...divs].forEach(div => {
  const angle = randomInteger(0, 180);
  // определить в какой четверти находится элемент
  const x = r * Math.cos(angle);
  const y = r * Math.sin(angle);
  
  div.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`;
});


// маленький бонус
let angle = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  center.style.transform = `translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(${angle}deg)`;
  angle += 0.5;
}, 16);
```

```css
.center {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.center div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.center div:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}
.center div:nth-child(2) {
  background: blue;
}
.center div:nth-child(3) {
  background: yellow;
}
.center div:nth-child(4) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='center'>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: вы все это сами считаете ?я про косинус и синус которые есть у вас в функции?

Comment: @Demon__ANT это стандартные функции JS

Comment: да я погуглил . спасибо  :)